# VBA- EXCEL - I cannot paste my data on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

My code is working at 90% because when I am about to finish it, and I want to paste data that I previously copied from another sheet, the code is interrupted and I can't find a way to make it functional.

I am copying data from the sheet "Table1" and I am pasting it in a workbook called "REPORT CC_MACRO" in the sheet "base table".

The code breaks at

```
    Once cell D3 is selected, paste the data that was copied in previous steps.
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

```
Sub BASEV1OK()
    Dim wsOrigen As Worksheet
    Dim wsOrigen2 As Worksheet
    Dim wsDestino As Worksheet
    Dim rngOrigen As Range
    Dim rngDestino As Range
    Dim rngOrigen2 As Range
    Dim ultFila As Long
    
    ' Definir la hoja de trabajo Original -    Dim wsOrigen As Worksheet
    Set wsOrigen = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("original")
    
    ' Obtener la última fila en la columna S -     Dim ultFila As Long
    ultFila = wsOrigen.Cells(wsOrigen.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row
    

'    ----------------------------
    
'' RANGO PARA ORDENAR COLUMNAS A O P - Definir el rango de datos de origen excluyendo la primera fila y limitando hasta la columna S
'Set rngOrigen = wsOrigen.Range("A2", wsOrigen.Cells(wsOrigen.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp))
    
    ' RANGO PARA ORDENAR COLUMNAS A O P - Definir el rango de datos de origen excluyendo la primera fila y limitando hasta la columna S
    Set rngOrigen = wsOrigen.Range("A2:S" & ultFila)


     
    
    ' Ordenar por las columnas A, O y P de menor a mayor
    MsgBox "Ordenando datos por las columnas A, O y P..."
    With rngOrigen
        .Sort Key1:=.Columns("A"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
              Key2:=.Columns("O"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
              Key3:=.Columns("P"), Order3:=xlAscending, _
              Header:=xlYes
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Ordenación completada."
    
'    ----------------------------
    
    'RANGO PARA FILTRAR COLUMNAS Definir el rango de datos de origen excluyendo la primera fila
    Set rngOrigen2 = wsOrigen.Range("A1", wsOrigen.Cells(wsOrigen.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(, wsOrigen.Cells(1, wsOrigen.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
    
    
   ' Aplicar filtro en la columna R
MsgBox "Aplicando filtro en la columna R..."
With rngOrigen2

    ' Limpiar filtros existentes
    .AutoFilter
    
' Aplicar filtro personalizado en la columna R
rngOrigen2.AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:=Array("** Sin Uso **", "Clientes en mora", "En Juicio", "Sin Operar"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

End With

MsgBox "Filtro aplicado."

'    ----------------------------


' Seleccionar las celdas visibles después de aplicar el filtro
On Error Resume Next ' Ignorar error si no hay celdas visibles
Dim rngFiltrado As Range
Set rngFiltrado = rngOrigen.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ' SE TOMA EL RANGO SIN LOS TITULARES PARA QUE NO LO ELIMINE
On Error GoTo 0 ' Restaurar manejo normal de errores

' Verificar si se encontraron celdas visibles
If Not rngFiltrado Is Nothing Then
    ' Eliminar las filas filtradas
    rngFiltrado.EntireRow.Delete
Else
    MsgBox "No se encontraron datos filtrados para eliminar.", vbInformation
End If

' Limpiar filtro
wsOrigen.AutoFilterMode = False

'    ----------------------------


'    ' Seleccionar todo el contenido activo de la hoja
'    rngOrigen.Copy

' Copiar solo las celdas desde A hasta S en lugar de todas las columnas
wsOrigen.Range("A2:N" & ultFila).Copy



    
    MsgBox "Tabla copiada"
    
    
        ' Crear una nueva hoja llamada "Tabla1"
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Tabla1"
    
'    ----------------------------

          ' Definir la hoja de trabajo Tabla1
    Set wsOrigen2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabla1")
    
'    ----------------------------
    
        ' Definir la hoja de destino
    Set wsDestino = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabla1")
    
    
'    ' Pegar los datos en la hoja de destino (solo las columnas A a S)
'wsDestino.Range("A1:N" & rngOrigen.Rows.Count).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
        ' Pegar los datos en la hoja de destino (solo las columnas A a S)
    wsDestino.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    
    
        ' Limpiar el portapapeles
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
'    ' Eliminar la fila de títulos en la hoja de destino - NO SE USA YA QUE ESTOY PEGANDO TABLA SIN TITULOS
'    wsDestino.Rows(1).Delete
    
    ' Limpiar filtros en la hoja de origen
    wsOrigen.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    
    
'    ----------------------------
    
' ------Verificar si el archivo "REPORTE CC_MACRO" está abierto
    If WorkbookIsOpen("REPORTE CC _MACRO.xlsm") Then
    
        Dim wsReporte As Worksheet
        Set wsReporte = Workbooks("REPORTE CC _MACRO.xlsm").Sheets("Tabla Base")
                   
        
        ' 2. Si está abierto, activar la hoja "Tabla Base" y seleccionar la celda D3
        With wsReporte
            .Activate
            .Range("D3").Select
        End With
        
        
        ' 3. Una vez seleccionada la celda D3, pegar los datos que se copiaron en pasos anteriores
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        
        ' 4. Desactivar modo de copia
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        
'         ' --------Pegar los datos desde el array al rango de destino
'        rngDestino.Resize(UBound(rngOrigen.Value, 1), UBound(rngOrigen.Value, 2)).Value = rngOrigen.Value
        
        
        ' 5. Mostrar mensaje de éxito
        MsgBox "Datos pegados exitosamente."
        
        ' 6. Mostrar mensaje si el archivo "REPORTE CC_MACRO" está cerrado
    Else
        MsgBox "El archivo 'REPORTE CC _MACRO.xlsm' no está abierto.", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub

Function WorkbookIsOpen(workbookName As String) As Boolean
    Dim wb As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Workbooks(workbookName)
    WorkbookIsOpen = Not wb Is Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

I need to find the error in my code or the suggestion to modify the copy and paste line in a new workbook in the selected sheet and cell "D3".

Comment: [es.so] is the place for this question. This is an English language site. If you had to use a translator to provide the English version because you were unable to do so yourself, you're also not able to answer any additional questions or understand an English answer.

Comment: At this comment you delete the Copy mode `' Limpiar el portapapeles
    Application.CutCopyMode = False`

Comment: ^^^^^ Copy/Paste operations should happen as closely as possible to each other. Otherwise you run the risk of some other operation clearing the clipboard ... which you appear to have done programmatically.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido 33pl! Tómese un tiempo para leer la introducción a Stack Overflow y obtenga su primera insignia. Somos un poco diferentes de otros sitios. Así es como... https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Welcome 33pl! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to work all your data with arrays.

```
Public dataArr
Sub Read()
    dim ws as worksheet
    set ws = activeworksheet 'or any other worksheet
    with ws
        dataArr = .cells(1, 1).currentregion 'CurrentRegion picks all the table at cell "A1". In your case, it may takes until column S and last row. Easier way ;)
    end with   
End Sub
```

you can print (show to screen) your array at any other sheet

```
sub printArr()
    Dim wsOutput as worksheet
    set wsOutput = worksheets("Whatever")
    with wsOutout
        .range(.cells(1, 1), .cells(ubound(dataArr)), .cells(ubound(dataArr, 2))) = dataArr
    End With
End Sub
```

with this data array, before printing, you can do anything, like sorting, filtering, etc.
you can find any function for sorting arrays thru the web, here's an example of sorting an array:

PS: I've literally copied this code from my projects. Is really useful for me.

```
Sub sortMyArray()
    dataArr = sortArray(dataArr, True, 15, True, False, 16, False, True)
'this sortArray function example in this sub, sorts the array first from the column 15, ascending and doesn't contain numbers. After that, is sorts with the column 16, descending, and this column contains numbers
End Sub


Function sortArray(arr As Variant, hasHeader As Boolean, ParamArray arrParameters() As Variant) As Variant
'arrParameters = array(nColumn, isAscending, isNumeric)
Dim numRows As Long, numCols As Integer
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim temp As Variant, parametre As Byte
Dim firstRow As Byte, columna As Integer

numRows = UBound(arr, 1)
numCols = UBound(arr, 2)

If numRows < 1 Or numCols < 1 Then sortArray = arr: Exit Function 'if is empty, quit

firstRow = IIf(hasHeader, 2, 1)

For parameter = 0 To UBound(arrParameters) Step 3
    Dim nColumn As Long, isAscending As Boolean, isNumber As Boolean
    nColumn = arrParametres(parametre)
    isAscending = arrParametres(parametre + 1)
    isNumero = arrParametres(parametre + 2)
    
    For i = 1 To numRows
        For j = firstRow To numRows - i
            'Compare each value
            Dim compareResult As Integer
            compareResult = 0
    
                If isNumber Then ' if is numeric
                    compareResult = IIf(arr(j, nColumn) > arr(j + 1, nColumn), 1, -1)
                Else
                    compareResult = StrComp(arr(j, nColumn), arr(j + 1, nColumn), vbTextCompare)
                End If
                'compare result returns 1, -1 o 0. if = 0 they are equal, if 1 is bigger, -1 is smaller
                If Not isAscending Then compareResult = -compareResult
    
                If compareResult > 0 Then
                    For column = 1 To numCols
                        temp = arr(j, column)
                        arr(j, column) = arr(j + 1, column)
                        arr(j + 1, column) = temp
                    Next column
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    Next parameter

sortArray = arr
End Function
```

Another question, putting msgBox informing everything to the user like you've done, is not a good way. You can try a better thing posting info messages like this shown above:

```
Sub updateStatusBar()
    Application.StatusBar = "Message to show..."
End Sub
```